When will there be an LTS version of VirtualBox 7.x for 22.04.4?
Got a recent LTS update of VirtualBox 6.1 on 22.04.4 which I expected would fix the requirement to downgrade my kernel version to 5.15.0-113, but nope.
VirtualBox 6.x is no longer supported by Oracle, the current LTS update doesn’t work because of the kernel needing to be downgraded and the most recent update is just a bundle of December 2023 bug fixes released days before support ended.
It is unclear to me why this was pushed to LTS since it doesn’t work.
When will we get a LTS version of VirtualBox 7.x?  Will we have to go to 24.04.4 to get this?

This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Virtual Box is its own product and company.

This question is similar to: Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 24.04.4 is scheduled to be released in early 2026; why did you mention that respin of the current LTS? Virtualbox 7 is available for the latest LTS release of Ubuntu.

This has to do with "Ubuntu Software" that is included in the 22.04.4 release.  That version of VirtualBox is Version 6.1.50-dfsg which no longer works with 22.04.4.  A new update was just pushed out which still doesn't work.  Who tests this stuff.  Yes VirtualBox is "its own product and company" (Oracle actually) and I have done what everyone else has done and uninstalled 6.1 and installed 7.x by hand.  Do I have to wait until 2026 when 24.04.4 comes out for "Ubuntu Software" to include VirtualBox 7.x?  Karel's answer would suggest yes.

It works properly for the volunteers who do the testing. If it doesn't work for you, then it's up to you to do the troubleshooting to figure out why.
